# How can I add a cache buster URL to my audio?

Tags: html5-audio, browser-cache

I need to add a cache buster extension to a streaming URL in my HTML5 audio player. The URL should be changed from: "192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3" to: "192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3?cb(random number)" so that the browser sees the stream as new and won't play from cache.

The HTML5 player itself is rendered by my CMS upon login and is using simple HTML5 audio tags. I found some scripts here but I do not know the correct "grammer" on how to add them to my audio player.

If that won't work, is there a way to have .htaccess rewrite the URL?

Here is the iFrame that contains the Drupal website and the audio player:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
                background: #333333;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                border: 0px;
                }
iframe {
                width: 100%;
                height: 92%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                border: none;
                display: block;
        }
  </style>
<body>

<?php
print('<iframe id="drupal_site" src="http://test.zoootradio.com" height="92%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.

print('<audio id="player" controls>');
print('<source src="http://192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">');
print('</audio>');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried adding no cache directives in the header of the iFrame and to player part of the iFrame, but they do not always work on all browsers.

Here are the two scripts I found that will add a cache busting extension to the streaming URL.

1.

```
function callback() {
  var url = "http://192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3?cb=" + new Date().getTime();
  var audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.load();
  audio.play();        
}
```

2.

```
var audioPlayer =  $('<audio src="/' + mp3FileName + '?cb=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + '" type="audio/mpeg" controls></audio>');
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using PHP so just let the server side do it for you

```php
print('<source src="http://192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">');
```

Should become

```php
print('<source src="http://192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3?'.base64_encode(time().microtime()).'" type="audio/mpeg">');
```

So what this does is use [`time()`](https://php.net/time) and [`microtime()`](https://php.net/microtime) concatenated and then [`base64_encode()`](https://php.net/base64_encode) the resulting string this is because base64 is URL safe and removed any none URL safe chars without putting URL encoding into the URL GET query string.

Now while this is not the only way it's the simple way I use to get around browser caching